# Large figure with caption partially displayed/unable to spread caption onto the next page

Tags: captions, subfig, error-writing

I have tried every option that I can find and am not able to figure out a solution. I have a large figure with subfigures and my boss is requiring very long captions for everything. The problem I am running into is that when I compile the code the caption is truncated instead of continuing onto the following page. I am completely lost and freaking out a bit because my thesis is due quite soon. Any help would be greatly appreciated !

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    %FosTrap Scheme
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\textwidth}   
        \centering      
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/trap scheme dreadds.png}
        \caption{}   
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}

     %Injection Area and Representative Slice
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/viral_injection_scheme.png}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadd_ExpressionZoom.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadds_LatencyMount.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    
    %Appetitive/Proceptive Behaviors
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadds_latencySucMount.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadds_rejection.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \captionsetup{parbox=none}
    \caption{\textbf{Chemogenetic inhibition of fosTRAP2 neurons does not alter female receptive behaviors}}
    \footnotesize
    \textbf{a} FosTrap2 induction protocol. Mice are first ovariectomized the injected with AAV-DiO-hm4d. Following two bouts of sexual habituation, the female is undergoes fosTRAPPing protocol immediatedly after the third session. Two weeks later, fosTRAPPed feamles are then assayed two more times (one session with Saline, one session with DCZ)
    \textbf{b} Viral injection site for DREADDS virus and representative image showing DREADD expression in the lPAG. Cells colored in red are positive for hm4d-mCherry (fosTRAPPED cells).
    \textbf{c} Latency to first mount attempt by males in females treated with either saline or DCZ
    \textbf{d} Latency to first mount with intromissions performed by the male. This event marks the transition between the appetitive stage and consummatory stage of sexual behavior
    \textbf{e} Percentage of rejected mount from the female. Percentage was determined by the number of rejections with respect to all mounting events (rejections, mounts w/probing and mounts w/intromissions). Black dots in all graphs represent individual animals between testing sessions. Bars represent mean of all animals +s.e.m; NS P>0.05, * P<0.05, ** P<0.01, *** P<0.001, paired \textit{t}-test
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to put the entire figure* into a savebox and use `\vsplit` to break it into two figure*s.

The enumerate was a gratuitous choice on my part.  It isn't really needed.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}
  
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\global\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{%
    \centering
    %FosTrap Scheme
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}   
        \centering      
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=4cm]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/trap scheme dreadds.png}
        \caption{}   
        \label{}
    \end{subfigure}

     %Injection Area and Representative Slice
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth, height=1cm]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/viral_injection_scheme.png}
        \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth, height=1cm]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadd_ExpressionZoom.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=2cm]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadds_LatencyMount.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    
    %Appetitive/Proceptive Behaviors
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadds_latencySucMount.png}
        \caption{} 
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.475\textwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2-PAG/DREADDS Inactivaton/dreadds_rejection.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \captionsetup{parbox=none}
    \caption{\textbf{Chemogenetic inhibition of fosTRAP2 neurons does not alter female receptive behaviors}}%
    \footnotesize
\begin{enumerate}\def\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}%
    \item FosTrap2 induction protocol. Mice are first ovariectomized the injected with AAV-DiO-hm4d. Following two bouts of sexual habituation, the female is undergoes fosTRAPPing protocol immediatedly after the third session. Two weeks later, fosTRAPPed feamles are then assayed two more times (one session with Saline, one session with DCZ)\\
    \item Viral injection site for DREADDS virus and representative image showing DREADD expression in the lPAG. Cells colored in red are positive for hm4d-mCherry (fosTRAPPED cells).\\
    \item Latency to first mount attempt by males in females treated with either saline or DCZ\\\
    \item Latency to first mount with intromissions performed by the male. This event marks the transition between the appetitive stage and consummatory stage of sexual behavior\\
    \item Percentage of rejected mount from the female. Percentage was determined by the number of rejections with respect to all mounting events (rejections, mounts w/probing and mounts w/intromissions). Black dots in all graphs represent individual animals between testing sessions. Bars represent mean of all animals +s.e.m; NS P>0.05, * P<0.05, ** P<0.01, *** P<0.001, paired \textit{t}-test
\end{enumerate}}% end tempbox
\setbox0=\vsplit\tempbox to \textheight
\unvbox0
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure*}
\unvbox\tempbox
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```